# Programs which are not editors to batch compress images/photos in Linux/Windows?

Tags: images, image-processing

I have a large set of photos taken with my camera which takes a lot of space, and time to upload to Drop Box to share with people. Photoshop can be used to save them to a lower resolution but opening photoshop to do it takes a long time. 
Which programs for Linux or Windows would do batch compression without visible loss of quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (Free, open source, cross-platform, CLI) to compress all your images at once.

Comment: D., it says it does a lot of things "*Use ImageMagick to resize, flip, mirror, rotate, distort, shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves."* but it doesn't mention compression anywhere from what I can see...

Comment: @Vass e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262050/395857